# Suma de valores de una tabla en Javascript

Tags: javascript, tablas

soy medio nuevo en esto de JavaScript y quiero sumar los valores de mi tabla (columna/precio) a medida que voy agregándole productos a la misma, y que este resultado se vaya posicionando en la columna/total. E intentado de diversas formas (for, foreach, while, etc...) pero todo ha sido en vano, seria una alivio si me pueden dar una mano. Muchas gracias. Doy un poco de contexto ya q me pide seguir escribiendo... Empeze a estudiar js hace no mucho y como prueba tenia que aplicar datos a esta tabla desde 3 formas diferentes tal y como se puede apreciar.
alfinal solo me entrevero y me complico la existencia.

```js
//Desestructuración de Arreglo
const nombres = ["game 1", "game 2", "game 3", "game 4"];
const precioNombres = [500 , 250 , 1200 , 400];

const [a, b, c, d] = nombres;
const [w, x, y, z] = precioNombres;

//JSON (agregar todos los productos button)
function allProductsProgramar(){
    allProducts();
};

function allProducts(){
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open('GET', 'js/catalogo.json', true);
    xhttp.send();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            let datosJson = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            let res = document.getElementById("tabla");
            
            for(let item of datosJson){
                //item. (lo que desee visualizar de mi JSON)
                //console.log(item)
                res.innerHTML += `<tr>
                <td>${item.name}</td>
                <td>$${item.price}</td>
                <td>$</td>
                </tr>`;
            };
        };
    };
};

//Función invocada desde form con onclick
function capturar(){

    //Constructor de objetos
    function persona(nombre,precio){
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.precio=precio;
    };
    
    //variables
    let nombreCapturar = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    let precioCapturar = precioNombres;

    //Datos primitivos (condicionales + AND)
    nombreCapturar === "game 1" && (precioCapturar = w);
    nombreCapturar === "game 2" && (precioCapturar = x);
    nombreCapturar === "game 3" && (precioCapturar = y);
    nombreCapturar === "game 4" && (precioCapturar = z);

    if (nombreCapturar !== "game 1" && nombreCapturar !== "game 2" && nombreCapturar !== "game 3" && nombreCapturar !== "game 4"){
        //sweet alert (libreria)
        swal({
            title: "Oops!",
            text: "Este producto no existe!",
            icon: "error",
            dangerMode: true,
          });
        getElementById("tabla").remove;
    };

    nuevoSujeto = new persona(nombreCapturar,precioCapturar);
    
    //Función a invocar
    agregar();
};

//Array
let baseDatos= [];

//invocación de funcion
function agregar(){
    baseDatos.push(nuevoSujeto);
    console.log(baseDatos);
    document.getElementById("tabla").innerHTML += '<tbody><td>'+nuevoSujeto.nombre+'</td><td>$'+nuevoSujeto.precio+'</td><td>$'+calcularTotal.total+'</td></tbody>';
    
};

//DOM (Event)
function programarBtn(){
    Boton;
    borrar;
    comprar;
};

function Boton(){
    const guardarBtn = document.querySelector('#boton1');
    const guardarBtn2 = document.querySelector('#boton2');
    const guardarBtn3 = document.querySelector('#boton3');
    const guardarBtn4 = document.querySelector('#boton4');
    
    guardarBtn.addEventListener('click', firstBoton);
    guardarBtn2.addEventListener('click',secondBoton);
    guardarBtn3.addEventListener('click',thirdBoton);
    guardarBtn4.addEventListener('click',fourthBoton);
};

function borrar(){
    const borrarBtn = document.querySelector('#delete');

    borrarBtn.addEventListener('click', borrarBtnTotal);
};

function comprar(){
    const comprarBtn = document.querySelector('#buyed');

    comprarBtn.addEventListener('click', comprarBtnTotal);
};

//Botones
function firstBoton(){
    document.getElementById("tabla").innerHTML += '<tbody><td>'+a+'</td><td>$'+w+'</td><td>$'+''+'</td></tbody>';
};

function secondBoton(){
    document.getElementById("tabla").innerHTML += '<tbody><td>'+b+'</td><td>$'+x+'</td><td>$'+''+'</td></tbody>';
};

function thirdBoton(){
    document.getElementById("tabla").innerHTML += '<tbody><td>'+c+'</td><td>$'+y+'</td><td>$'+''+'</td></tbody>';
};

function fourthBoton(){
    document.getElementById("tabla").innerHTML += '<tbody><td>'+d+'</td><td>$'+z+'</td><td>$'+''+'</td></tbody>';
};

function borrarBtnTotal(){
    location.reload();
};

function comprarBtnTotal(){
    location.href = "pages/compra.html";
};
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]!  Antes de nada recomendate que leas [ask] y que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio y a elaborar buenas preguntas. Tu pregunta carece de un [example] porque le falta el HTML y un ejemplo básico del json que obtienes en tu petición ajax. Puedes editar la pregunta pulsando sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la misma y agregar esa información para que podamos ayudarte mejor y podamos usar tu código para reproducir tu escenario en busca de una solución. Gracias por colaborar con el buen funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Veo mucho código que no hace nada, como la función `programarBtn` o como las 4 líneas tras el comentario "Datos primitivos". Revisa la sintaxis de Javascript